# Serde Deserilize with keyword tag

Tags: rust, serde

The following code snippet is how I
use serde::Deserialize;

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct OuterStruct{  
  name: String,
  value: i64,
  inner: Wrapper,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct structA{
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  ttype: String
  field: String
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct structB{
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  ttype: String
  field: String
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Wrapper{
  typea(structA),
  typeb(structB),
}
```

To my understanding the `#[serde(tag = "type")]` specifies the field type which decides what enum's variant to use for `Deserialize`.

But when I use it like that I get errors like

```
missing field ``type`` at line 1 column 177
```

I've also tried #[serde(tag = "ttype")] which is the original field name but to no avail.

---

My current workaround is:

Like cafce25 mentioned in the answer
removing `ttype` from the struct.
And also do

```rust
impl Wrapper{
  fn get_type(&self)->String{
    match &self{
      Wrapper::typea(_)=>"typea".to_string(),
      Wrapper::typeb(_)=>"typeb".to_string(),
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway for me to keep `type` field within the struct?

Comment: please provide complete example of input.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `#[serde(tag = "type")]` is to not have a redundant field on your structs since the information is encoded in the type, just remove the `ttype` fields from your structs.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct StructA {
    field: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct StructB {
    field: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Wrapper {
    TypeA(StructA),
    TypeB(StructB),
}
```